# inlineEdit Cancel button suppose to work this way?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

So I am try this sample directly from the developer guide, and if you were do an inline edit of the last name field, for example, and want to revert back to the original data by hitting cancel it doesn't do that.

Instead, it set the value to that field, but it is not saved into the record yet. Is that normal behavior?
I was expecting to revert back to the original data from the record.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" id="editButton" value="Edit"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
            <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastname}">
                <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                    hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                    changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
            </apex:outputField>
            <apex:outputField value="{!contact.accountId}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!contact.phone}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```